# How do I check if all Dagger dependencies for a component are scoped?

Tags: dagger-2

I’m converting a large service to use Dagger, and I have a component with a lot of dependencies in the generated graph, and I want to ensure everything is scoped.

Initially, I tried to look at all the modules of the component to ensure that all their `@Provides` were annotated with a scope. However, one can have a class that uses `@Inject`, not have any `@Provides` methods in the modules, and that be unscoped if not specified on the class.

Right now, in order to check if I missed anything, I go into the generated code and look to see if anything is missing a double-checked locked provider. However, this isn’t very efficient and feels error-prone, as there are cases (such as a component dependency) where we don’t need a provider, since we reference the dependent component directly.

Is there a simple way to check for unscoped bindings for a component? I’d like to make sure that for the component, only one instance of every object in its graph is created in its lifetime.